# How to remedy for accidently making a commit into the master branch instead of my feature branch

Tags: git

Locally, I forgot to create a feature branch from the master branch, and then made a commit of my changes into the master branch.

How can i correct the mistake, so that the commit is removed from the master branch, and is made into a new feature branch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```bash
git checkout master
git checkout -b my-feature-branch
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git checkout my-feature-branch
```

Explanation:

1. First we make sure we are on the `master` branch.
2. Now we create a new feature branch, bringing along the latest commit.
3. We move back to the `master` branch.
4. We reset the `master` branch to the commit before the last one.
5. We go back to the feature branch to continue working on it.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider the situation

before committing

```
... -- A
       ^
       |
       master
```

after commit

```
... -- A -- B
            ^
            |
            master
```

To resolve situation, you need to perform the following steps:

**method 1**

1. rename "master" branch to "feature" branch with `git branch -m feature`

```
... -- A -- B
            ^
            |
            feature
```

2. recreate "master" from the previous commit with `git checkout -b master A`

```
... -- A -- B
       ^    ^
       |    |
       |    feature
       |
       master
```

**method 2**

1. create new branch with `git checkout -b feature`

```
... -- A -- B
            ^
            |
            feature *
            master
```

2. return to master branch with `git checkout master`

```
... -- A -- B
            ^
            |
            feature
            master *
```

3. reset changes in master with `git reset --hard HEAD~1`

```
... -- A -- B
       ^    ^
       |    |
       |    feature
       |
       master
```